# How to hedge/protect my stocks that do not have an option chain?

Tags: put-options, hedging, covered-call-writing, over-the-counter

I've recently invested in a couple of OTC stocks (1st time exploring the OTC market) and unfortunately there's no option chain available. Question is, how can I protect those stocks in particular from downside risk when there are no options available?  They've (as you can imagine in this market) appreciated quite a bit, but remain volatile.

I believe that I can reach out to my brokerage and inquire about buying OTC options, but would like to explore all possibilities.  Please note, that I have done extensive research on my situation and have yielded little success.

My hope is that I find my answer within this community I was lucky enough to stumble upon.

Big thanks in advance

Comment: A stop loss sell order limits your downside, and only fails in the event of a sudden, large drop. It's also susceptible to drops that recover quickly, unlike put options. Would that work?

Comment: @DStanley per what Bob had mentioned, since these stocks in particular happen to be penny stocks, I'm rather limited in what I can do. From what I'm gathering, even if I were to use the stop loss with SPY, it wouldn't apply to what my type of stock.  Of course, I would like to exhaust any possibilities if you and Bob are willing to entertain this subject matter further.  Rest assured I am still continuing my research and appreciate your contributions.

Comment: sell half of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to accurately hedge a stock that doesn't offer options.  There are some things that you can do but there's no guarantee that they will be effective and they could even make things worse:

- You could use the options of a similar stock or even short some stock (pairs trading which can be risky)
- You could use the options of SPDR ETF if you are concentrated in a sector
- You could use an index based ETF like SPY if you have broad based exposure

If by OTC market you're referring to penny stocks then none of this is applicable.  And reaching out to your broker to create off exchange option agreements isn't going to get you anywhere unless you own size and it's worthwhile to your broker to get involved.  You would really need to seriously understand how options work if you're going to craft your own agreements.

Comment: Understood.  Yes, these 4 stocks that I am attempting to address are penny stocks and only a few thousand shares each.  They have appreciated at a rate far greater than expected (I would imagine quite normal for our current market) which, makes me believe this is not sustainable in the short term.  I did choose these companies with the intention to stay long, however, would like to preserve that gain best way possible.  It has followed SPY rather closely in the past, however in recent times it's been more volatile.

Comment: Penny stocks have high risk, high reward and they are often used to scam inexperienced investors.  A good rule of thumb is don't gamble with more than you can afford to lose.  If you happen to be someone who can discern the crap from the quality and achieve gains, work out disciplined risk management to protect/book gains.  There are no options that will help you with these low priced issues which can be very volatile.

Comment: Thank you Bob, I agree.  Thats why I've never had much of an appetite for penny stocks. However,  I've gone through my routine fundamental and qualitative analysis applying a "logical" approach to my decision and found these few to be worth the monetary risk.  Where I find myself questioning my next steps is with this disruption by today's "social media" and how it seems to be influencing the market.  I'm usually long and in all the years investing, I have never seen movement like this in the past.

Comment: So I have some decisions to make.  Stay long per usual and keep to my 3 year plus time horizon or take profits from these clearly abnormal gains, changing my normal investment strategy.  I'm no professional by any means, however have been investing both in the market and elsewhere for a number of years.   Thanks again for sharing the knowledge.

Comment: What's your primary concern, fear (giving up your profit) or greed (getting more profit)?  You can't have both.  Are you a trader who's happy with the bird in hand or an investor willing to risk current gain while seeking long term gain?  A factor for me would be the size involved.  Is this a quick $500 gain or a quick $5,000 gain (not asking for details).  And when there's no good answer, I'll scale out of the position.  Book some gains now.  If price goes up, the remainder still makes money.  If it goes down and I still believe, buy it back. And if it range trades, wash, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Frankly loss aversion has never played much of a factor for me.  I typically I see respectable gains over the course of a year or longer and It's made me quite comfortable keeping with my existing strategies.  However, in this particular situation each have had more than 13k+ in gains. Which I'm accustomed to seeing over the course of seven plus months where as this happened in less than half that.  You're insight is extremely helpful and has allowed me arrive more confidently at my original decision.  Scale out. buy back accordingly.  It should have been obvious to me. Helps to bounce it off.

Comment: Just to add to my last post as it came to mind and may be helpful.  I also account for my short term gains tax when making my calculations.  That does play a factor in my decisions.